# JTabbedPane spacing at the top

Tags: java, jframe, jtabbedpane

I have a JTabbedPane inside a JFrame. I would like it so that the border extends right to edges of the JFrame on the top, left and right borders. How can I do this? At the moment there is a space at the top which I am really struggling to get rid of. Any ideas?

Here is an example of what it currently looks like?

```
package tapptest;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class Tapptest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
        jtp.addTab("one", new JLabel("one"));
        jtp.addTab("two", new JLabel("two"));
        jtp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(440, 200));
        jtp.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.BOTTOM);
        frame.add(jtp);
        frame.setSize(415,180);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice defaultScreen = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        Rectangle rect = defaultScreen.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        int x = 10;
        int y = (int) rect.getMaxY() - (frame.getHeight() + 50);        
        frame.setLocation(x, y);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }

}
```

Comment: `jtp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(440, 200));` might be the first mistage

Comment: I'm not sure what you want is achievable, at least not without implementing your own UI delegate

Comment: ok, so you think I would be best just leaving it as is?

Comment: I think it's going to be aweful lot of hard work to fix it